# Keras: masking zero-padded input for non-RNN

Tags: python, keras

A colleague of mine pointed out the very cool option to use `sample_weight` instead of a masking layer when you need to mask input to a non-RNN in Keras.

In my case, I have 62 columns in the input, with the 63rd being the response. Over 97% of the nonzero entries in the 62 columns are contained in the first 30 columns. I'm trying to just get this working, so I'd like to weight the last 32 columns to be 0 in training, essentially creating a 'poor-man's mask'.

This is an 8-class classification task, using an MLP. The response variable has been transformed using the `to_categorical()` function in Keras.

Here's the implementation:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=X.shape[1], init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
hist = model.fit(X, y, 
                 validation_data=(X_test, ytest), 
                 nb_epoch=epochs_, 
                 batch_size=batch_size_, 
                 callbacks=callbacks_list, 
                 sample_weight = np.array([X.shape[1]-32, 30]))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
in standardize_weights
assert y.shape[:sample_weight.ndim] == sample_weight.shape
```

How can I fix my `sample_weight` to 'mask' the first 32 columns of the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample weight isn't working like that:

> `sample_weight`: optional array of the same length as `x`, containing weights to apply to the model's loss for each sample. In the case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape `(samples, sequence_length)`, to apply a different weight to every timestep of every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify `sample_weight_mode="temporal"` in `compile()`. [source](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit)

In other words, this setting puts different weights on the **samples** of the training data, not on the features of each sample. This is used only at training step.
I think you should use masking if you don't want the layer to use those features. Or just remove them from your dataset? Or, if it's not too complicated, let the network learn by itself which the useful features are.

Does this help?